# change value of backing bean of web page element with javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, html, javabeans

how can I change the value of a backing bean web element from javascript?

the xhtml:

```
<h:form >
<input type="hidden" id="elementid" name="element" value="#{BackingBean.elementid}" />
```

the bean:

```
public class BackingBean implements Serializable {

protected String elementid = "";
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('elementid').value = 'new value';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the Id of the element used in Javascript has to be correct.  So if the object is in a form then the form name has to be added to the component name.  The best way to see this is to look at the source of the page in the browser.

So in the example above an id should be added to the form.  And the input should be converted to jsf as well, so we would call getElementById with this id: 'mainForm:formid:elementid'

document.getElementById('mainForm:formid:elementid').value = 'new value';